# 'non-static reference member, can't use default assignment operator'

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

I get this error when i try to compile my code:
`non-static reference member ‘Timestep& Timestep::previousTimestep’, can’t use default assignment operator`

I create one `Problem` which creates a `Timestep` a reference to the this `Timestep`should be stored in the vector `solution`. Besides i want to store a reference to a previous `Timestep` - and for the first Timestep that would be a reference to itself...

I read that i need to define an own operator if i have `const` members in a class what i try to set equal. However, removed all `const` elements form the code and it still don't work. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```
class Problem {
public:
    void initialTimestep(arma::vec ic);
private:
    std::vector<Timestep> solution;
};

void Problem::initialTimestep(vec ic){
    Timestep myFirstTimestep(starttime, ic, nodes);
    solution.push_back(myFirstTimestep);
}



class Timestep {
public:
    Timestep(double starttime, arma::vec initialCondition, arma::vec nodelist);
private:
    Timestep& previousTimestep; //const
};

Timestep::Timestep(double starttime, vec initialCondition, vec nodelist)
: previousTimestep(*this)
    {
    //do stuff
}


int main() {
    int k = 3; //subdomains
    vec v = linspace(0., 1., k+1); //node spacing
    vec ic= ones<vec>(k+1); //initialconditions
    Problem myProblem(v, ic, 0., 1., 0.1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No default assignment operator was created for your class `Timestep` because it contains a reference (which cannot be set later. it basically is a constant pointer to non-const data).
`solution.push_back(myFirstTimestep)` requires the asignment though (or move with c++11) so you will have to define your own assignment (or move) operator (which of course you will not be able to do unless you change `Timestep& previousTimestep` to `Timestep *previousTimestep` in which case the default assignment will work as well).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The comment about using `move` helped. In the end I use this `solution.emplace_back(starttime, ic, nodes)` to solve my problem (needs C++11). Seems like it is also the preferred way form a performance point of view. Besides it also resolves problems with const elements.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write your own assignment operator for the Timestep class (`operator=`).

Alternatively, you can use a Timestep pointer instead of a reference inside the Timestep class. That'd be my personal preference in this case. The compiler imposes a lot fewer rules about pointers, for various reasons.